# Does Griffa's Adaption skill affect the flamethrower consumption?

Tags: mad-max

Through Griffa you can upgrade the skill called Adaption which will let Max "consume less fuel while driving".

Will this skill also affect the amount of fuel needed for the flamethrowers you can mount on the side of the Magnum Opus?

Comment: PCGamer claim that the Adaption ability **does** reduce the amount of fuel your flame throwers will use [here](http://www.pcgamer.com/mad-max-guide-tips/).

Comment: @DrRDizzle thx for the link, that are quite some useful tips.

Comment: The only reason I haven't put it as an answer is because I have no idea if PCGamer are considered a reliable source or not.

Comment: I will test this later today and post the result here. Maybe you can put it as an answer if i can prove it.

Comment: @DrRDizzle i really looks like it reduces the amount. I couldn't upgrade the skill completely cause i haven't unlocked all stages yet. But even after upgrading the flamethrower uses fuel like it was leaking somewhere.

Comment: I haven't got that far in the game yet, but it's useful to know about this early on. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PCGamer in [this article](http://www.pcgamer.com/mad-max-guide-tips/), the Adaption ability **does** reduce the amount of fuel that flame throwers on the Magnum Opus will use.

From the article, when referring to the use of the Adaption skill and flame throwers (emphasis mine);

> This will change all of the sudden late in the game when you get the chance to add flamethrowers to your car. They're useful, no doubt, for keeping cars from smashing into your sides and setting enemies on fire, **but boy do they drink up the go-juice. In other words, throw a token into Adaptation every so often, even if you feel like you don't need it**.